# Qt C++ Accessing window methods from another class

Tags: c++, qt

Im using Qt for a project, I made a QWidget and it works fine. In my widget class i have 3 methods, Quiz is my window,-

```
void Quiz::appendConsole(QString string) {
    ui->console->append(string);
}

void Quiz::setInput(QString string) {
    ui->input->setText(string);
}

QString Quiz::getInput() {
    return ui->input->text();
}
```

and in the header class they are listed as public as shown -

```
namespace Ui {
class Quiz;
}

class Quiz : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
     Quiz(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Quiz();
     void appendConsole(QString string);
     void setInput(QString string);
     QString getInput();

private slots:
    void on_button_clicked();

    void on_input_returnPressed();
private:
    Ui::Quiz *ui;
};
```

But when i try access any of these three methods from another class it fails with the error - 
error: call to non-static member function without an object argument

```
void startQuiz() {
    Quiz::setInput("Hello");
}
```

does anyone know the proper way to access these classes or how these classes should be setup?

Comment: Wait, let me get it straight: you are getting an error upon **calling** the method, but didn't think it was important to show **how** you are calling the method? Why?

Comment: chill dude ill add it

Comment: Well as the error message you get states, `Quiz::setInput` is not a static method, so you can not call it without an object. Either pass a `Quiz` object to the other class, or use a signal.

Comment: The problem with passing quiz as an object is that for some reason it cause the widget to attempt to be created before the application which cause it to crash

Comment: What do you mean *the widget to attempt to be created before the application*? You mean `QApplication`? Are you using global/static variables to create this object?

Comment: i just did Quiz quiz; and then quiz.setInput... and it crashed giving me the error QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Comment: Well it depends a lot where did you put `Quiz quiz;`. Also, this will create a new `Quiz` instance. By the way, does `startQuiz` function even belong to a class?

Comment: Before even starting with Qt you should consider learning some C++ basics. Your question has nothing to do with Qt at the moment. It is purely C++ question and it entry level question.

Comment: ok then answer the question instead of insulting me?

Comment: unless you can't which seems to mean you should consider learning some C++ basics.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a function statically, even though it is not a static function. You need an object to call this function. Either pass your `Quiz` object to this other class, or use a signal.

Option 1: *Pass a reference of `Quiz` to your other class*

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>

class Quiz : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Quiz(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        label = new QLabel;
        layout()->addWidget(label);
        resize(400, 400);
    }
    void setInput(const QString &input) {
        label->setText(input);
    }
private:
    QLabel *label;
};

class OtherClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OtherClass(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent), quiz(0) {}
    void setQuiz(Quiz *quiz_ptr) {quiz = quiz_ptr;}
    void startQuiz() {
        if(quiz)
            quiz->setInput("Hello");
    }
private:
    Quiz *quiz;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Quiz quiz;
    OtherClass otherClass;
    otherClass.setQuiz(&quiz);
    quiz.show();
    otherClass.startQuiz();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Option 2: *Use a signal*

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLayout>

class Quiz : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Quiz(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        label = new QLabel;
        layout()->addWidget(label);
        resize(400, 400);
    }
public slots:
    void setInput(const QString &input) {
        label->setText(input);
    }
private:
    QLabel *label;
};

class OtherClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    OtherClass(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    void startQuiz() {
        emit changeInput("Hello");
    }

signals:
    void changeInput(const QString &input);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Quiz quiz;
    OtherClass otherClass;
    QObject::connect(&otherClass, &OtherClass::changeInput, &quiz, &Quiz::setInput);
    quiz.show();
    otherClass.startQuiz();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an instance of the Quiz then you can call the method.

```
Quiz *quiz = Quiz();
quiz->setInput("Hello");
```

The other possiblility is that you mean setInput to be a static method.

In which case declare it like this:

```
class  Quiz : public QWidget
{
    ...
    static setInput(QString string);
    ...
};
```

Comment: gives me the error: No viable conversion from 'Quiz' to 'Quiz*'

Comment: `new Quiz()` required here, at least.